# Is there a View Will Appear, from specific View Controller method?

Tags: ios, stack, segue, pushviewcontroller

I have a home-screen, which has a push segue to various other view controllers. However, when I return from one (and only one) of these view controllers back to the home screen, I want the home-screen to reload one of its functions. The viewWillAppear method is useful (if I implement it on the home screen) because it is called when I return to the home screen, but is there something I can add, that will essentially check "was I sent back to the home-screen from -this specific- view Controller"? Not very eloquently worded I apologise.

The way I am doing this at the moment is to define a universal boolean variable, which becomes true when I am on the special view controller, then in the viewWillAppear method, if the boolean == true I reload the function. I don't like using these universal variables though, it feels error prone.

n.b. When I say universal variable, I mean one that is defined above the class, this may not be the proper term

Comment: Using your `BOOL` instance variable is a fine approach.

Comment: Thanks, is there no way I could do it without having to add code to both of the view controllers though?

Comment: Why would the code be in both?  It should all be in the presenting controller.

Comment: The viewWillAppear code would be in the presenting view controller, but I have put the Bool = true into the viewDidAppear of the receiving view controller, is this wrong?

Comment: What I would do is set the `BOOL` in the presenting view controller at the time it presents the view controller. There is no need for the presented view controller to have any knowledge of any of this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sent from another view controller back to the home screen, are you using an unwind segue?  If so, the home view controller should have a method of this form:

```
 - (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue{
 }
```

Inside this method, you can check if the sourceViewController is of a certain class:

```
if([unwindSegue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[otherTypeOfviewController class]]){
     //perform the tasks you need carried out
}
```